# Why do BLDC motors require feedback, whereas AC motors do not?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, feedback, ac-motor

I was delving into the functional difference between 3-phase AC motors and 3-phase BLDC motors, and was wondering what would happen if a BLDC motor was run without feedback to its controller.

I found an article somewhere that was stating that one of the functional reasons why AC motors are beneficial is that they are "self-correcting".  There is something about operating the electrical sine wave from -Vmax to +Vmax that allows the motor rotor to stabilize, and if the AC motor rotor did somehow skip a winding/phase, that it would self correct.  It wouldn't be pretty, and there would be mechanical shock/vibration issues, but the motor would settle down.  Somehow that stability doesn't exist with BLDC motors that operate on a sine wave from 0 to +Vmax.  That if a BLDC motor didn't have feedback to a controller that told the controller which phases to energize, and the rotor did somehow skip a phase or winding, that the purely positive sine wave would not provide the "self-correcting" phenomena and the BLDC would do very bad things until it somehow just fails and everything breaks.  Basically AC motors are able to run on open-loop VFDs, while BLDC motor controllers require closed-loop feedback.

Is this explanation real?  Or did I just read some dumb article?  Unfortunately I do not remember where I read the article so I cannot reference it.

Comment: If you want precision angular control from a BLDC motor then you need feedback. If you just want a grunting_spinning thing at a fixed RPM then you don't need feedback.

Comment: Do you mean feedback to control position or speed, or feedback to the controller for commutation purposes (e.g. hall sensors)?

Comment: This has to do with how they work.  BLDC spins at speed of magnetic field.  No slip.  \$n = n_S\$ IM spins at less than speed of magnetic field.  There is slip. \$n < n_S\$.  As load gets heavy, slip increases.  In BLDC, there is no slip, so if load gets heavy and lock between rotor and stator is lost.  Motor will stall.

Comment: Most (not all) AC motors are induction motors, which slip a little when running, and slip a lot while starting. So they don't run at synch speed by design. You CAN run BLDC motors open loop : that's how sensorless ones start. (Once it can sense the motor running, the controller switches to closed loop, to get the best performance and efficiency.) That's why sensorless tend to run rough for a second before smoothing out.

Comment: another reason you want control on a DC motor is related to how they can stall and increase the current abruptly, having a feedback allows you to react to those situations very quickly.